# Trying to paste Values from formula Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

This is just a snippet of my code from Google App Script which iterates through each row in columns 1, 2, 3. If an edit is made in column 3, an incremental ID will be generated and a concatenation of the same row and different columns will also be generated - in this case Column D, E, and F. I am struggling with figuring out a way to change the formulas into values. What am I missing here?

```
// Location format = [sheet, ID Column, ID Column Row Start, Edit Column]
var locations = [
  ["Consolidated Media Plan",1,9,3] 
];

function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  //Entry data
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();

  // Location Data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  function getNewID(){
    function IDrange(){
      var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
      var lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();

      return sheet.getRange(IDrowStart,IDcol,lastRow-IDrowStart).getValues();
    };

    //Get largest Value in range
    function getLastID(range){
      var sorted = range.sort();
      var lastIDval = sorted[sorted.length-1][0];

      return lastIDval;

    };
    //Stores leading letters and zeroes and trailing letters
    function getLettersNzeroes(id){

      //Get any letters or zeroes.
      var re = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0])$");
      var letterZero = [];
      for(char = 0; char < id.length; char++){
        if(re.test(id[char])){
          letterZero.push([char,id[char]]);// [[position, letter or zero]]
        };
      };

      // Categorize letters and zeroes into start and end blocks
      var startLetterZero = "", 
          endLetter = "",
          len = letterZero.length - 1;
      for(j = 0; j < letterZero.length; j++){
        if(letterZero[j][0] === j){
          startLetterZero += letterZero[j][1];
        }else if(letterZero[j][1] !== "0" && letterZero[len][0] - (len - j) == letterZero[j][0]){
          endLetter += letterZero[j][1];
        };
      };
      var startNend = {"start":startLetterZero,"end":endLetter};

      return startNend;
    };

    //Gets last id number. Adds 1 an checks to set if its  new length is greater than the lastNumber.
    function getNewNumber(id){
      var removeZero = false;

      var lastNum = parseInt(id.replace(/\D/g,''),10);//Remove letters
      var newNum = (lastNum+1).toString();

      if(lastNum.toString().length !== newNum.length){
        var removeZero = true;
      };
      var newNumSet = {"num":newNum, "removeZero": removeZero};

      return newNumSet
    };

    var lastID = getLastID(IDrange());
    var lettersNzeroes = getLettersNzeroes(lastID);
    var newNumber = getNewNumber(lastID);

    //If the number is 9,99,999,9999 etc we need to remove a zero if it exists.
    if(newNumber.removeZero === true && lettersNzeroes.start.indexOf("0")  !== -1.0){
      lettersNzeroes.start = lettersNzeroes.start.slice(0,-1);
    };

    //Rejoin everything together
    var newID = lettersNzeroes.start +
                newNumber.num +
                lettersNzeroes.end;

    return newID;  
  };

  for(i = 0; i < locations.length; i++){
    var sheetID = locations[i][0],
        IDcol   = locations[i][1],
        IDrowStart = locations[i][2],
        EditCol = locations[i][3];

    var offset = IDcol - EditCol;
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();



    if(sheetID === sheet.getName()){
      if(EditCol === col){
        //ID Already Exists the editing cell isn't blank.
        if(cell.offset(0,offset).isBlank() && cell.isBlank() === false){
          var newID = getNewID();
          cell.offset(0,offset).setValue(newID);
          cell.offset(0,-1).setFormulaR1C1('=concatenate(R[0]C[-1],"_",INDEX(Glossary!K:K,MATCH(R[0]C[2],Glossary!J:J,0)))');







        };
      };
    }; 
  };        
};
```

**EDIT:**
This is my full code, I have been unsuccessful with trying to retrieve just the values of the formula within the same (i.e, If C9 gets edited, a formula with the values specific to the 9th row should be populated)

Also, I've tried to add an index/match formula to the concatenation formula at the bottom of the code - it works as expected on the google sheets, but when I run it with the script it pastes the correct formula but it returns a #NAME? error message. However, when I copy and paste the exact same formula in the cell, it works perfectly, any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: are you trying to set the result of the R1C1 formula back into the same cell?

Comment: Yes, I am! But I can't seem to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I know it's not exactly the same thing but I didn't have access to getNewId()

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet1')return;
  //e.source.toast('flag1');
  if(e.range.columnStart==3 && e.range.offset(0,1).isBlank() && e.value) {
    //e.source.toast('flag2');
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(e.value);
    e.range.offset(0,2).setFormulaR1C1('=concatenate(R[0]C[-1],"_",R[0]C[-2],"_",R[0]C[-3],"_",R[0]C[-4])');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I see what you're doing, but can't get it quite right with the code I have - i'll keep playing around with this. I've made some changes to my original post